# Substitution failure with `std::function` and previously deduced template parameter - why?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename> 
struct S { };

void g(S<int> t);

template <typename T>
void f(T, std::function<void(S<T>)>);
```

When attempting to invoke

```
f(0, g);
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'f'
>     f(0, g);
>     ^
>
> note: candidate template ignored: could not match 
>       'function<void (S<type-parameter-0-0>)>' 
>       against 'void (*)(S<int>)'
> void f(T, std::function<void(S<T>)>);
>      ^
> ```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Qk0pL1)

<strike>While I understand that generally the type of the `std::function` parameter can't be deduced as it is a non-deduced context</strike>

In this case `T` can first be deduced by the passed argument `0`, and then substituted into `std::function<void(S<T>)>` to get `std::function<void(S<int>)>`.

I would expect that after deducing `T=int`, the compiler would substitute `T` everywhere in the signature and then attempt to construct the `std::function` parameter with the argument `g`.

**Why is that not the case?** I presume that the ordering in which substitution/deduction happens has something to do with this, but I'd like to see the relevant Standard wording.

*Bonus question:* is this something that could potentially be changed in a future Standard while preserving backwards compatibility, or is there a fundamental reason why this kind of substitution doesn't work?

Comment: Here is the same thing without `std::function` or function pointers, to simplify a bit: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SHXtwh

Comment: You can still use `template <typename T>
void f(T, std::identity_type_t<std::function<void(S<T>)>>)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is `std::identity_type_t` up for standardization?

Comment: @MaxLanghof https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> While I understand that generally the type of the std::function parameter can't be deduced as it is a non-deduced context.

It is not a non-deduced context. Quite the contrary. Because deduction for the parameter of `std::function` is attempted, but the argument is *not* a `std::function`, deduction fails. The deduction of template arguments from function arguments must agree for all function arguments. If it fails for one, it fails entirely.

> **[temp.deduct.type]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct#type-2) In some cases, the deduction is done using a single set of
>   types P and A, in other cases, there will be a set of corresponding
>   types P and A. Type deduction is done independently for each P/A pair,
>   and the deduced template argument values are then combined. If type
>   deduction cannot be done for any P/A pair, or if for any pair the
>   deduction leads to more than one possible set of deduced values, or if
>   different pairs yield different deduced values, or if any template
>   argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template
>   argument deduction fails.

Making the type of the second function parameter into a non-deduced context is actually how one can overcome the error.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename> 
struct S { };

void g(S<int> ) {}

template <typename T>
void f(T, typename type_identity<std::function<void(S<T>)>>::type) {}

int main() {
    f(0, g);
}
```

`T` is deduced successfully from the first function argument, and there is nothing left to deduce. So the dedcution is deemed a success.

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81c0638cb30193de)

Answer (score 7):

> While I understand that generally the type of the `std::function` parameter can't be deduced as it is a non-deduced context, in this case `T` can first be deduced by the passed argument `0`.

This is not true.  `T` is deduceable in this context.  If you change the code to

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::function<void(S<T>)>);

int main()
{
    f(std::function<void(S<int>)>(g));
}
```

the code would compile and `T` is correctly deduced.

Your issue is that you are passing an object to the function that it can't extract `T` from.  The compiler will not do any conversion of the function arguments when it tries to deduce `T`.  That means you have a `int` and a function as the types passed to the function.  It gets `int` from `0`, then tries to get the type from the `std::function` you pass in the second parameter but since you didn't pass a `std::function` it can't extract `T` and because of that, you get an error.